# JS: Dropdown toggle "class"

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, drop-down-menu

I have a little issue and need your help. I have a Dropdown with to selction-options »green« and »blue« and I need to toggle a class by selecting one of them.

JS-Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/K94mC/

My Code:

```
$(".btn_blue").click(function() {
$(".element").toggleClass("element_blue", 0);
});

$(".btn_green").click(function() {
$(".element").toggleClass("element_green", 0);
});
```

Can anybody see where my mistake is?

Chris

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://jsfiddle.net/5DkVN/1/

```
 <select class="dropdown">
   <option class="btn_blue" data-class="element_blue">blue</option>
   <option class="btn_green"  data-class="element_green">green</option>
 </select>

 <div class="element">Text</div>




$(document).ready(function() {
   $('.dropdown').change(function(){
      $(".element").attr( "class", $(this).find('option:selected').data('class')+ " element");
  });        
});
```

Comment: or more concise: `$(".element").attr('class', "element "+ this.value);` See: http://jsfiddle.net/QCPjx/

Comment: Why not simply use <option value="..." /> instead of data-attributes...? ;)

Comment: @sibbl value might be used for other purposes. That's why I prefer using data attributes for such tasks.

Answer (score 1):

You have to use dropdowns change event rather than click of any option.
below code may help you to understand

```
$(".dropdown").change(function(){
   if($(this).val() == 'blue')
      $(".element").toggleClass("blue");
   else if($(this).val() == 'green')
      $(".element").toggleClass("green");
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Besides adding JQuery, use the change event handler to get notified when the selection of a dropbox changes and then get the value of the dropdown:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".dropdown").change(function() {
        var value = $(this).val();
        if(value == "blue") 
            $(".element").removeClass("element_green").addClass("element_blue");
        else if(value == "green")
            $(".element").removeClass("element_blue").addClass("element_green");
    });        
});
```

[See this working fiddle of your demo.](http://jsfiddle.net/K94mC/10/)

Comment: that looks very promising! I will try it with my complex example and see if it works ... please stand by ;D